# How to Remove Child Node from XML with Index number with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

Sorry I am beginner powershell developer. So I have an XML doccument that looks like this:

```
<task>
   <list>list1</list>
   <list>list2</list>
   <list>list3</list>
   <list>list4</list>
   <list>list5</list>
</task>
```

So I want to input parameter to execute ps1 script
like this 
.\deletetask1.ps1 3

expect this xml

```
<task>
   <list>list1</list>
   <list>list2</list>
   <list>list4</list>
   <list>list5</list>
</task>
```

Could Anyone help me to code  deletelist powershell script or suggest me How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: From this answer, you need first to define how to land on the node you need to remove. In @david-wall answer, he is using XPATH expression. The rest is processing XML with Powershell for which many examples can be found around, including the ones included in the answers here.

Answer (score 0):

I try this . I 'm not sure It's good Way or Not ?

```
function delete { 

[xml]$xml = (Get-Content $filename)
$nodedelete = $xml.task.ChildNodes.item($param)
$xml.task.RemoveChild($nodedelete)
$xml.Save($filename)
}
```

I have some question for my script.
How to check amount of Childnodes Item? Because My code have some error when delete childnodes.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd like to mention (as I am not high enough reputation to comment yet) that you should really attempt to show things you have tried or researched before bringing the question here. The purpose of SO is not to have others write code for you. That being said.

You should check out [Dynamic Casting](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2007/10/29/dynamic-casting/) to help accomplish this. If your goal is to read the data into a variable, then remove the entry, this is probably what will fit your needs. I encourage you to take a look at this, and then play around with tab completion of the variable to see what you can learn. Additionally, check out [this blog post](http://jon.netdork.net/2013/01/09/removing-xml-elements-using-powershell/) as well.

If you get stuck, or need a quick and dirty example, see below:

```
$test = "<task>
   <list>list1</list>
   <list>list2</list>
   <list>list3</list>
   <list>list4</list>
   <list>list5</list>
</task>"

[xml] $myxml = $test

$remove = $myxml.task.SelectSingleNode("//list[.='list2']")

$remove.ParentNode.RemoveChild($remove)
```

Once you have some time to play around with this, you may consider updating your question to show what you have tried, and ask questions on what you don't understand.